# CSS - Syntax to select a class within an id

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the selector syntax to select a tag within an id via the class name?  For example, what do I need to select below in order to make the inner "li" turn red?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #navigation li
        {
            color: green;
        }

        #navigation li .navigationLevel2
        {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>Level 1 item
            <ul class="navigationLevel2">
                <li>Level 2 item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
#navigation .navigationLevel2 li
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Only if the example shown is all the markup. For all you know, the markup needed is more complicated. I based my answer off the information given.

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm trying to select _.class1-1_ classes within the _#container-1_ id, by using  **_#container-1 .class1-1 { Styles }_** but it's not working. I inspect elements and I see it doesn't assign the styles at all.

Comment: it is not working for me either

Answer (score 9):

This will also work and you don't need the extra class:

```
#navigation li li {}
```

If you have a third level of LI's you may have to reset/override some of the styles they will inherit from the above selector. You can target the third level like so:

```
#navigation li li li {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's two options.  I prefer the navigationAlt option since it involves less work in the end:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #navigation li {
      color: green;
    }
    #navigation li .navigationLevel2 {
      color: red;
    }
    #navigationAlt {
      color: green;
    }
    #navigationAlt ul {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>Level 1 item
      <ul>
        <li class="navigationLevel2">Level 2 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="navigationAlt">
    <li>Level 1 item
      <ul>
        <li>Level 2 item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navigationLevel2 li { color: #aa0000 }
```

Comment: IF this does the trick without applying it to unwanted li:s, then this is the way to go, since it has fewer selectors and thus is faster. At least according to Google's page performance advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to drill down to the last li.

```
    #navigation li .navigationLevel2 li
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that you can select the `LI` that's a direct child of the given id using the `>` selector (called child selector):

```
#navigation>li
{
    color: blue;
}
```

and therefore the deeper nested one

```
#navigation>li>ul>li
{
    color: red;
}
```

without the need of the additonal css class.