# Targeting a class when inside another class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am creating a div that will have a default style but is also going to have various options for different styles depending on the content. My goal is to be able to have these styles take effect only when nested inside of the custom class name. Kind of hard to explain verbally so I'll give some code examples of what I mean:

This will be the html structure for the default view:

```
<div>
  <div class="default"></div>
</div>
```

This will be the html structure for the custom view:

```
<div class="custom">
  <div class="default"></div>
</div>
```

So basically I need to be able to write a class that will say "redefine these styles on default only when default is nested inside of custom"

Really just looking for confirmation on the syntax involved here.

My first thought is to write something like:

```
.custom .default {
  declaration: attribute;
}
```

I'm just a little unsure of whether this will only target default when it's inside of custom or if this will globally redefine default, I can't live test it just yet because ftp transfer hasn't yet been set up for me on this server.

Thanks in advance for any clarity on this!

Comment: Trust your first tought... It's correct!

Comment: that code will work perfectly as it is

Comment: `.custom .default` is a descendant selector which represents `.default` elements that are descendants of `.custom` elements. Therefore your first thought is correct.

Comment: "*I can't live test it just yet because ftp transfer hasn't yet been set up for me on this server"*? what? you could've opened any online editor or created an html file with notepad and test it yourself -__-

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the confirmation guys, sorry for the time waster whoever it was that downgraded me haha. I would have tested it myself but without boring with too many details it's been very hard to duplicate the environment locally so I just wanted to make sure I had it right ahead of time.

@TJ: There are specific things about the development environment with this company that make it difficult to duplicate locally without being able to upload to the cms, if you're so irritated with a question then doesn't it make more sense to ignore it and move on?

Comment: I couldn't find an exact similar question on SO in order to close this one as duplicate. The most similar one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140646/css-syntax-to-select-a-class-within-an-id :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that's right. This will target any `.default` contained by a `.custom` (at any point in its ancestry) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqon4592/)):

```
.custom .default {
    color: red;
}
```

<sub>See [the descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant) and [others](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Combinators).</sub>

And yes, it can override declarations specified by `.default` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcpLfgd9/)):

```
.default {
  color: green;
}
.custom .default {
  color: red; /* overrides green */
}
```

<sub>Have a look at [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).</sub>

Comment: @Roko no offense, but I've already linked to the other combinators for reference. I'd rather not clutter the answer further.

Comment: @c np. You nailed it +1

Answer (score 6):

So, canon's answer is enough... But, just for the *clarity* that you asked.

You can restrict your selector to target only a nested element, with two methods:

- **Descendant Selector**: It's written with a white space and targets the child element at any nested level inside the parent:

[**MDN ref docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

```
.parent .child {
    /*styles*/
}
```

- **Child Selector**: It's written with a `>` charachter, and targets the child only if it is **directly** nested, an immediate child:

[**MDN ref docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

```
.parent > .child {
    /*styles*/
}
```

Comment: @Shomz Don't forget [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796180/targeting-a-class-when-inside-another-class#comment40348271_25796180) :)

Comment: @HashemQolami Yeah, yeah, fixed the wording :)

Answer (score 1):

You were right. And if you want to make sure to target only the direct descendants, you can do this:

```
.custom > .default {
    declaration: attribute;
}
```

That would be helpful in case you had something like:

```
<div class="custom">
    <div class="default">
        <div class="default"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @canon Sorry, bad wording. I meant the first descendants.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will look for an element that has a class of `default` which is encapsulated within a parent with the class `custom`, any child nodes which match this rule will have the styling applied to them, you can create as many different themes for the same element as you wish, so long as you change the class.

So your code:

```
.custom .default {
    declaration: attribute;
}
```

Is perfectly correct.